# I can't login in windows 10 to search for app in the store

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, login-screen

I can't login in windows 10 to search for app in the store.

When I restarted my windows 10 computer, I got the following message:

> Something happened and your PIN isn't available. Click to set up your PIN again.

I clicked on "Set up my PIN"  which was the only option available on the screen. It asked me to search for an app in the store.

> You need to install an app for this task Would you like to search for one in the Store? Yes or No

When I clicked 'Yes', nothing happened. Please kindly help me.

Comment: What build of WIndows 10 are you running exactly?

Comment: Have you tried to Reset the Windows Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My cousin just had the same issue. First he rebooted after using his PC, and when he logged in, had no desktop, just a black screen with a cursor. Restored and deleted all files. Installed a few games, rebooted a couple times and was fine. Shut down for the night, turned it back on today, and now hes being asked to create a pin, and cannot. And safe mode is telling him to install an app, but neither response does anything. Rebooting into safe mode with networking, the oc just shuts down completely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).